# close the running application in vb.net from background

Tags: vb.net, ffmpeg

i want to stop the running (ffmpeg) process from background . i use the

```
  process.kill()
```

i wrote the code . but in this process the output file is getting corrupted.

```
Dim pProcess() As Process = Process.GetProcesses
  For Each p As Process In pProcess
   If p.ProcessName = "ffmpeg" Then
    p.WaitForExit(1000)
    p.Kill()      
    p.Close()
  End If
Next
```

is there any other method to terminate the process without file being corrupt

thanks

Comment: If the process isn't complete, it is expected that it produces incomplete file (and thus probably corrupted) as well. Unless the file itself does not require to be complete to be uncorrupted, this task will not be easy. It might be impossible...

Comment: Doe ffmpeg return some kind of indication that it's finished? Maybe you could look for that? Process.ExitCode I believe is the keyword you would use.

Comment: when i am trying to  terminate forcefully...it did not give any indication....

Comment: it is .mp4 file , when i use cmd ... i terminate by ctrl+c.. the file comes without any corroupt .